gbrief2 - How to add pagenumbers to first page and a postscriptum
I need to include the total page numbers to my letters, which I create using gbrief2.
By default, gbrief2 shows the \thepage on page 2+. I'd need something like Page X of TOTAL_PAGES. I can't manage to override this behavior.
Additionally, if I have more than 1 page, I'd need to show Page 1 of TOTAL_PAGES on the first page, too.
How would I achieve both changes?
Output vs. desired outcome

MWE
\PassOptionsToPackage{unicode}{hyperref}
\PassOptionsToPackage{hyphens}{url}
\PassOptionsToPackage{dvipsnames,svgnames,x11names}{xcolor}
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,english]{g-brief2}

\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}

\usepackage{iftex}
\ifPDFTeX
  \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
  \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
  \usepackage{textcomp} % provide euro and other symbols
\else % if luatex or xetex
  \usepackage{unicode-math}
  \defaultfontfeatures{Scale=MatchLowercase}
  \defaultfontfeatures[\rmfamily]{Ligatures=TeX,Scale=1}
\fi
\usepackage{lmodern}

\usepackage{enumerate}
\usepackage{eurosym}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage{bookmark}

\trennlinien
\AdressZeileA{Sender}
\AdressZeileB{Some other place}
\AdressZeileC{XYZ}

\hypersetup{
  pdfauthor={John Doe},
  pdflang={de-DE},
  colorlinks=true,
  linkcolor={black},
  filecolor={Maroon},
  citecolor={Blue},
  urlcolor={Blue},
  pdfcreator={LaTeX via pandoc}}

\author{John Doe}
\date{}

\Postvermerk{}
\RetourAdresse{Sender, Some other place, XYZ}
\Adresse{To Somehwere\\Some place}
\Datum{\today}
\Betreff{}
\Anrede{Dear You}%
\Gruss{Kind Regards}{1cm}
\Unterschrift{John Doe}

\setlength\textheight{185mm}

\begin{document}
\begin{g-brief}

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur
sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et
dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et
justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea
takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit
amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor
invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At
vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd
gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.

\newpage

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur
sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et
dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua.


\end{g-brief}
\end{document}


This is an answer for the first question (page x of y). The other issue is unrelated, you may consider to ask that as a separate question (and edit it out of this one).
As shown in, e.g., How can I add "page # of ##" on my document?, you can use the lastpage package to get a reference to the last page. Then you can add this to the header using \thepage\ of \pageref{LastPage}.
Now the question is how to get this into g-brief2. A relatively easy way is to modify the source code of the class. This can be done with the etoolbox package, which can change commands temporarily from the user document.
The code for the header for page 2 and further is found in the command \ps@regularpage in g-brief2.cls (the \ps stands for 'page style'). The original version of the header is:
\textsc{{\Large\quad}\name\hfill\pagename\ \thepage\quad\hfill\datum}}

So, in small caps, first the \name variable (if it is set), then the word 'Page' (localized), the the page number \thepage, then the date.
We want to change \thepage into \thepage\ of \pageref{LastPage}. In etoolbox this is done with the command \patchcmd, which has five arguments: the command to be modified, the search text, the replace text, and two arguments that are executed if the patch succeeds or fails, respectively. These two can be left empty, they are mainly useful during testing.
In this case:
\patchcmd{\ps@regularpage}{\thepage}{\thepage\ of \pageref{LastPage}}{}{}

One issue is that this page style is already read and applied while loading the class, so before it is patched. Therefore it needs to be reapplied with \pagestyle{regularpage}. Also, because the command name contains an @ symbol, the patch needs to be surrounded by \makeatletter and \makeatother. The full patch is then as follows:
\makeatletter
\patchcmd{\ps@regularpage}{\thepage}{\thepage\ of \pageref{LastPage}}{}{}
\pagestyle{regularpage}
\makeatother

This results in the following output for page 2:

Now we want to do the same for page 1. Here however the page number is conditional on the number of pages. First we need to convert the LastPage reference into a number that can be used in calculations, and it should have a default value to make sure the compilation doesn't fail during the first LaTeX run when the final page number is not known yet. Both things can be done using \getrefbykeydefault from the refcount package, as suggested in the manual of the lastpage package. If this number is bigger than 1 then the page numbers should be shown:
\ifnum\getrefbykeydefault{LastPage}{page}{1}>1\pagename\ \thepage\ of \pageref{LastPage}\fi

Note that the first number {1} is the default value, and the second >1 is the actual comparison.
This can go in a patch of the page style for the first page, which is \ps@firstpage. Strangely, this header is defined to be 180mm wide, which pushes the page numbers out of the margin as the letter itself is 165mm wide. So the patch should be a bit bigger to include the \parbox that sets the width. Also this allows to reshuffle the \Large and \name and \textsc commands a bit so the name will be large, the page numbers are normal size, and both are in small caps.
So the second patch is:
\makeatletter
\patchcmd{\ps@firstpage}{\parbox{180mm}{\Large \textsc{\quad\name}}}{%
\parbox{165mm}{\textsc{{\Large\quad\name}\hfill\ifnum\getrefbykeydefault{LastPage}{page}{1}>1\pagename\ \thepage\ of \pageref{LastPage}\fi}}}{}{}
\makeatother

Result:

Full code with both patches:
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,english]{g-brief2}
\usepackage{lastpage}
\usepackage{refcount}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\makeatletter
\patchcmd{\ps@regularpage}{\thepage}{\thepage\ of \pageref{LastPage}}{}{}
\pagestyle{regularpage}

\patchcmd{\ps@firstpage}{\parbox{180mm}{\Large \textsc{\quad\name}}}{%
\parbox{165mm}{\textsc{{\Large\quad\name}\hfill\ifnum\getrefbykeydefault{LastPage}{page}{1}>1\pagename\ \thepage\ of \pageref{LastPage}\fi}}}{}{}
\makeatother

\trennlinien
\AdressZeileA{Sender}
\AdressZeileB{Some other place}
\AdressZeileC{XYZ}

\author{John Doe}
\date{}

\Postvermerk{}
\RetourAdresse{Sender, Some other place, XYZ}
\Adresse{To Somehwere\\Some place}
\Datum{\today}
\Betreff{}
\Anrede{Dear You}%
\Gruss{Kind Regards}{1cm}
\Unterschrift{John Doe%
\newline\newline\newline PS Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur
sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et
dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et
justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea
takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit
amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor
invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At
vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd
gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.}

\setlength\textheight{185mm}

\begin{document}
\begin{g-brief}
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur
sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et
dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et
justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea
takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit
amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor
invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At
vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd
gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.

\newpage

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur
sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et
dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua.


\end{g-brief}
\end{document}


Thank you for your very good and detailed answer. You've helped me a lot and increased my understanding of LaTeX in general.
